# Does every time I modal from a vie to another view the method viewdidload gets called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to figure out something about the view controller lifecycle, i understand that viewdidload gets called only once.

BUT, I have a situation were i have 2 view controllers, one is the main view controller and another table view controller.

In the main view controller i have 2 buttons, one for the table view and one to some other view.

The main vorw conrtoller viewdidload does happends once but, Whenever i modal to those other view controllers viewdidload gets call each time.

Im using `[self presentviewcontroller: self.navigationcpntroller animated:yes completion: nil]`

To modal to the other view controllers from my main view controller. And im using nibs.

What am i not understanding here :/
Tnx

Comment: to answer your question: yes.

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called when a view controller is initialized. You must be initializing your second view controller each time you transition.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is called for a view controller the first time the view controller's view has been loaded in the view controller's lifecycle.

If you create a new instance of a view controller each time it is presented then you will see `viewDidLoad` being called once each time it is presented.

If you create a view controller instance and reuse that same instance over and over, then `viewDidLoad` is only called once (the first time it is presented).

Since it is normal to create new view controller instances each time you need it, `viewDidLoad` will be called each time you present it.